# DS-160, Person/Entity paying for you trip

Tags: usa, f1-visas

I have received a fully funded Ph.D. offer from Florida State University. In my I-20 the estimated cost for 12 month is 52,690$ and student funding which involves tuition waiver, stipend and medical insurance subsidy is 52,791$. My personal funding is mentioned as 0$ in the  i-20 since  the funding from college completely covers the yearly expenses. Now my question is this.

In the DS-160 form there is a question "the person/entity paying for your trip". In this question are they asking who is paying for my flight ticket and the first month of living expenses when I won't be receiving my stipend or are they asking who is funding my entire Ph.D. ?

Let's assume they are talking about only the initial travel expenses. I am planning on borrowing money from my uncle for the initial expenses. So if I mention him as as the person paying for the trip what all documents would I need to bring to the interview as proof. Will a bank statement showing the transferred amount suffice? Or would I need to show his monthly income, income tax returns and an affidavit of financial support? Should I just mention myself as the person funding the trip and show them the bank statement containing the money?

Comment: Borrowing for a trip is bad, like really, it's not seen well. Get your uncle to directly sponsor your ytavel expenses